# android: sqlite database empty after phone restart or kill per taskmanager

Tags: android, sqlite

i have created a database in my android app:

```
Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
SQLiteDatabase db;
String path = "cultura.db";
db = context.openOrCreateDatabase(path, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);
```

ok if my app is killed by task manager or the phone is restarted the database is empty. does anyone have a solution????

Answer (score 0):

The code to create a database is as follows :

SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;

sampleDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(Constants.DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE,
                null);

The database shouldn't be empty even if the phone is restarted.

Did you properly created the tables & inserted the values ?

Comment: everything fine.......if a db is open and the programm is killed....then it doens not save the state